# Conditionally run CMake's CHECK_TYPE_SIZE

Tags: cmake, cmake-modules

Is there a way to conditionally run CMake's `CHECK_TYPE_SIZE` command?   `CHECK_TYPE_SIZE` is great for figuring out what the size of a struct is, but the problem is that over time someone might modify the header file with the struct to add new fields.  Seems like it's an accident waiting to happen when someone updates the struct but forgets (or doesn't know to) blow away the CMake cache.  Yes, you could put a note next to the struct to do a cache wipe if updated, but that doesn't really help when you have a multi-person project and someone else updated the header file.

I tried to do an `unset(HAS_MYVAR CACHE)` but that didn't seem to work as the function doesn't appear to be re-run.  Any ideas?

CODE:

```
CHECK_TYPE_SIZE("my_struct_t" MY_STRUCT_SIZE)
message("Struct size is ${MY_STRUCT_SIZE})

add_custom_target(get_size)
add_custom_command(TARGET get_size COMMAND echo ${MY_STRUCT_SIZE})
```

```
$ cmake -S . -B /tmp/test
...
Struct size is 40
...

$ cd /tmp/test
$ make get_size
40
Built target get_size
$ <mod stuct to be larger>
$ make get_size
40
Built target get_size
```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/CheckTypeSize.html), the command `CHECK_TYPE_SIZE` creates **two** variables: `<VARIABLE>` and `HAVE_<VARIABLE>`. Most likely, you need to clean them both for performing the check again.

Comment: My cmake foo is a little fuzzy, but afaik, this command runs in the "configure" stage.   When I go to re-run the cmake build, it sees that that the cache already exists and doesn't run the command at all (much like how `message` commands don't run on a re-build)

Comment: "and doesn't run the command at all (much like how `message` commands don't run on a re-build)" - The `message` command runs **unconditionally** every (re-)configuration. It seems your description doesn't correspond to your actual actions. Or you choose some ... unusual words for describe you problem/situation. Please, show the exact **code** (in form of [mcve]) of your attempt and show output of it.

Comment: I think you bolded the wrong words.  I think you meant to bold *re-build* and *(re-)configuration*.   I want the results of `check_type_size` to be dependent on the header, so if it changes, it gets re-computed.  If the command only runs during *configuration* then it's not going to do any good if the file changes at a later date and I go to *rebuild* the files, which seems like a large flaw

Comment: Oh, so you want to make the whole configuration process to depend on the file. In that case, see that question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246037/how-to-make-cmake-reconfiguration-depend-on-custom-file.

Comment: Thanks!  That appears to have done it.  I need to both `unset(HAVE_MY_STRUCT_SIZE CACHE)` and `set_property(DIRECTORY APPEND PROPERTY CMAKE_CONFIGURE_DEPENDS inc/my_header.h)`