# How can I add a step to the build phase in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I am trying to convert our installation process to use cmake instead of our old custom build that we have today. In the project we do have a few perl files that sometimes change that we want to include in the built product. In these perl files we want to set the shebang (#!/path/to/perl) during installation, so it can run on the system where cmake is run.

Usually I would use configure_file(), but due to the nature of configure_file() any `@Unidentified-sequence@` will default to an empty string, when using configure_file() with any other option than COPYONLY (https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/22740). This becomes inconvenient for perl scripts, as @ is used to define an array.

The workaround I have today is to read the file into cmake and use string replace,

```
file(READ "${srcDir}/${file}"  FILE_CONTENTS)
#I have full control over the files. Thus adding a custom variable, such as @PERLPATH@, instead of a REGEX, is possible
string(REGEX REPLACE "#!/[/A-Za-z_0-9.-]+/perl" "#!${PERL_PATH}" FILE_CONTENTS "${FILE_CONTENTS}")
file(GENERATE OUTPUT "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${destDir}/${file}" CONTENT "${FILE_CONTENTS}")
```

This works, but any changes to the perl files requires `cmake -B /path/to/build -S /path/to/source` to be rerun. Also, it will rerun this for any file and not only the changed files.

I would like it to automatically update the files when doing `cmake --build`. Further, I would also prefer to have a check whether the files are changed or not and only update them then (which requires old change data to be saved and thus cannot be done during configure, `cmake -B /path/to/build -S /path/to/source`).

I would appreciate if someone had a standardized solution to this, but as I understand it, this use case is not exactly supported in CMake. Thus I would consider it good enough with a workaround. Getting the change date is easy enough with `stat -c %y`.

Is there any way to force cmake to run some particular cmake code snippet during `cmake --build`, lets say the above example?

Comment: If you want to automatically re-run configuration stage if your template changes, then see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246037/how-to-make-cmake-reconfiguration-depend-on-custom-file). Note, that it is not possible to re-run configuration stage *partially*: the configuration is indivisible. If you want to only to regenerate a specific file, then use `add_custom_command`/`add_custom_target` approach. Within `COMMAND` you may specify any script which could perform you task. You could even write a CMake script and run it with `cmake -P <script>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the output file of this procedure is needed as a source file for any targets, use [`add_custom_command`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html). Otherwise, use [`add_custom_target`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html).

Since you've already written some CMake to perform the task, just put that CMake in its own `.cmake` file and run it in the custom command/target using `"${CMAKE_COMMAND}" -P <path to that script file>`. (see docs on `-P` [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#run-a-script)).

In the `DEPENDS` field, specify the path to the CMake script and the path to any input files that are required by the CMake script. You will need to pass the value of `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` to the CMake script in the command field with `"-DCMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR=${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}"`, since the script will not automatically have the same variables as the project that calls it (see docs on script-mode's `-D` flag [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-P-D)).

If the output file is needed as a source file for any targets (the `add_custom_command` route), then specify its path in the `OUTPUT` field, and then the custom command will be run as needed any time a target that needs that output file gets built. In the `add_custom_target` route, custom targets are always run, so if you want to have fancy logic that skips running if the input files haven't changed, I think you'll need to implement that in the script file itself, which you can do by using the [`if(file1 IS_NEWER_THAN file2)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#file-operations) command, and [`file(TOUCH)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#touch) to create a file with the timestamp of when the custom target body was last run (so if the touch file is newer than all the input files, just [`return`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/return.html)).

Comment: Sorry for late answer. I have tried this and it seems to work quite well so far. However, what I noticed is that I seem to need to add_custom_target to get the custom command to be picked up. Adding one custom target/custom command pair per file I want to configure/build will pick up any changes and rebuild the file if necessary. The problem though is that this is very slow, in case there are a few custom targets. Currently I struggle with how to deal with several OUTPUT in add_custom_command and DEPENDS in add_custom_target. Getting this "make[2]: *** No rule to make target".

Comment: @patrik "_I seem to need to add_custom_target to get the custom command to be picked up_" use custom command if the output is used as a source file of all targets that need it. Otherwise, use custom target.

Comment: @patrik "_I struggle with how to deal with several OUTPUT in add_custom_command and DEPENDS in add_custom_target_" show me what you are doing. You can reach me [in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/11107541)

Answer (score 1):

1. use `find_program()` to find `perl` and define e.g., `PERL_EXECUTABLE`
2. if `perl` is not found (dunno how critical it's for you) set `PERL_EXECUTABLE` to a default value, e.g., `/usr/bin/perl`, so `configure_file()` will always substitute `#!@PERL_EXECUTABLE@` in shebang to smth not empty
3. use `add_custom_command(<fixed-shebang>.perl...)` to run `cmake -P <your-script-with-configure_file>.cmake [<input-files>]` to produce the perl file(s) to install from their "templates"
4. use `install(<FILES|PROGRAMS> ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/<fixed-shebang>.perl)` command to install 'em to a desired location

This way edit files will "rebuild" 'em on `cmake --build …` and install fixed shebang versions on `cmake --install`.

Update:

According to the substitution problem, I can't reproduce:

1. I pick a random Perl module from my system (e.g., `Storable.pm` where `@` symbols exist) and copy it to a test directory as `Storable.pm.in`
2. add `#!@PERL_EXECUTABLE@` as the very first line in it
3. added a `subst.cmake` to the test directory with the following content:

```
message(STATUS "PERL_EXECUTABLE=${PERL_EXECUTABLE}")
configure_file(Storable.pm.in Storable.pm @ONLY)
```

3. run `cmake -DPERL_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/perl -P subst.cmake`
4. and then `diff Storable.pm.in Storable.pm`:

```
--- Storable.pm.in      2023-02-24 15:10:18.630116604 +0400
+++ Storable.pm 2023-02-24 15:12:00.587358711 +0400
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-#!@PERL_EXECUTABLE@
+#!/usr/bin/perl
 #
 #  Copyright (c) 1995-2001, Raphael Manfredi
 #  Copyright (c) 2002-2014 by the Perl 5 Porters
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but when it comes to (2), it will not work (or possibly work too well, depending on point of view). Perl itself uses @ to declare an array. It can look like this `@unique_object = grep { ! $temp{$_}++ } @Object_array;`, where configure_file() will replace `unique_object = grep { ! $temp{$_}++ }`  with an empty string. This is the root of the problem.

Comment: @patrik I've updated my answer w/ more details about substitition

Comment: A normal sum would break it, ´my $sum = 2+@t1+@t2;´. It will be replaced with `my $sum = 2+t2;`. Unfortunately the comment field is not useful for posting execution results, so you would have to try it yourself :(. Just adding a space between the operators would solve the issue in this case `my $sum = 2 + @t1 + @t2;`. However, I do not really trust a solution that might break for bad style, even if the language rules are still followed.

Comment: @patrik, I don't know Perl, is the other form of variable interpolation legal in it? I mean `${PERL_EXECUTABLE}` is valid Perl?